# Regexp type for number 0

Tags: php, regex

I want to 0 to 9 any number in input fields,so i check filter_var as below

```
<?php
$res['pno'] = filter_var($cond['pno'],FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
//check valid phone no
array('options'=>array('regexp'=>'/^0+[0-9]*$/')))?true:false;                
?>
```

It is ok when type any number ,But type 0 only ,it return **false** so how to check it to return **true** if i type 0 only?

Comment: What is the condition for valid phone number?

Comment: Try just `/^[0-9]*$/`. Or does it have to start with a `0`?

Comment: in the '0' only case , is it followed by end-of-line ? because if not, you get false

Comment: i tried it already bro @stribizhev ,still false

Comment: Please provide reproducible examples, not just `$cond["pdo"]` which only you know about. Also if it's for phone numbers, you don't want the most restrictive regexp. People typically want to enter things like `+1-123-49429`.

Answer (score 9):

The regexp itself was fine already.

Your actual issue is this:

```
 ?true:false
```

When [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) with the regex succeeds,  it will return a *string* of just `"0"`.

- Now if `?:` evaluates that in *boolean context*, then your final expression will simply be `false`.
- So wrap your filter_var() result check with [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen) or [`is_string`](http://php.net/is_string).

  ```
   = is_string(filter_var(…, …, …)) ? true : false;
  ```

  <sup>(Yes, the `?true:false` is *highly* redundant then.)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try:

```
if ($res['pno']!==false){
    // !== operator is important
    // because it checks value AND type of constant
    // string '0' is equal false if You checks only value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**  check condition with `!==false`  like following:

```
$cond['pno']="0";
$res['pno'] = filter_var($cond['pno'],FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
array('options'=>array('regexp'=>'/^0+[0-9]*$/')))!==false?true:false;                
var_dump($res['pno']);
$cond['pno']="01";
$res['pno'] = filter_var($cond['pno'],FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
array('options'=>array('regexp'=>'/^0+[0-9]*$/')))!==false?true:false;                
var_dump($res['pno']);
$cond['pno']="a";
$res['pno'] = filter_var($cond['pno'],FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
array('options'=>array('regexp'=>'/^0+[0-9]*$/')))!==false?true:false;                
var_dump($res['pno']);
```

**Output**

```
boolean true

boolean true

boolean false
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the PHP is a loosely typed language ( comparison is done not on the type of, but only on the value of a variable by default ), condition that returns string `"0"` is evaluated as [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues) and therefore else statement is executed. To check if value is empty and not a number use `empty( $num ) && !is_numeric( $num )`, for example:

```
$res['pno'] = filter_var( $cond['pno'], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array( 'options' => array( 'regexp'=>'/^0+[0-9]*$/' ) ) );
$res['pno'] = !( empty( $res['pno'] ) && !is_numeric( $res['pno'] ) );
```